# flask-login won't reject inactive users

Tags: python, mongodb, flask-login

I'm building a python app where I want users to initially be registered as inactive, so that I can approve them individually by switching the "active" attribute in my mongodb that stores my users. The issue that I'm having is that changing active to false doesn't seem to have any affect on the ability of the user to login.

Here's my login and register routes:

```
@auth_flask_login.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST" and "email" in request.form:
        email = request.form["email"]
        userObj = User()
        user = userObj.get_by_email_w_password(email)
        if user and flask_bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password,request.form["password"]) and user.is_active():
            remember = request.form.get("remember", "no") == "yes"

            if login_user(user, remember=remember):
                print user.is_active
                flash("Logged in!")
                return redirect('/notes/create')
            else:
                error = "invalid user"

    return render_template("/auth/login.html")


@auth_flask_login.route("/register", methods=["GET","POST"])
def register():

    registerForm = forms.SignupForm(request.form)
    current_app.logger.info(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and registerForm.validate() == False:
        current_app.logger.info(registerForm.errors)
        return "uhoh registration error"

    elif request.method == 'POST' and registerForm.validate():
        email = request.form['email']

        # generate password hash
        password_hash = flask_bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['password'])

        is_active = False

        # prepare User
        user = User(email,password_hash,is_active)
        print user

        try:
            user.save()

            flash("Please log in")
            return redirect('/login') #redirect to the login page when 


        except:
            flash("unable to register with that email address")
            current_app.logger.error("Error on registration - possible duplicate emails")

    # prepare registration form         
    templateData = {

        'form' : registerForm
    }

    return render_template("/auth/register.html", **templateData)`enter code here`
```

And my user model:

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = db.StringField(default=True)
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)
    isAdmin = db.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

I appreciate any help. I've been stuck on this for a few hours.

EDIT: @auth_flask_login is a Blueprint I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, there is no decorator as `@auth_flask_login` that Flask Login provides you.

You should have it like this for views that don't require login, and the example below in particular would be the case for a login page:

```
@app.route('/login', ...)
def login(...):
    ...
    some logic that goes for authentication
    ...
    login_user(user)  # user is a User object and this should login the user.
    ...
    more stuff
    ...
```

Read about the login_user function [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_user).

And a page that needs login:

```
@app.route('/some_page', ...)
@login_required
def someview(...):
    ...
```

You should read about [`login_required`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_required)

You can read more about this [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works)

EDIT:

```
from flask.ext.login import current_user

...

@app.route('/some_page', ...)
@login_required
def someview(...):
    ...
    if not current_user.active:
        ...  # 403 or some redirect, what ever you intend
    ...  # Stuff that should happen if the user was indeed active
```

Comment: Sorry, that's actually from the blueprint I'm using. 
 "
auth_flask_login = Blueprint('auth_flask_login', __name__, template_folder='templates')
". functionally @auth_flask_login should work the same for my routes and I'm not getting any errors on it.

Comment: That's alright, but for all view functions where you do require authentication you must use the decorator `@login_required` But at least for the view functions you have posted, I don't suppose it makes any sense for the user to be already logged in as they are the login and registration pages themselves. All other pages that require the user to be authenticated should have the `@login_required` decorator

Comment: Because your `Blueprint` namely `auth_flask_login` doesn't take of authentication. And of course you should consider using `current_user` from flask login to get the instance of the user if you wish to extend the scope of your authentication within the view function.

Comment: Right, I've got that set up already. The issue that I'm having is related specifically to the login process though: based on some trial and error, it seems that users who are logging in are always identified as active, even when active = false in the database.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that you had your own database column `active` As far as I know, flask login doesn't make use of that for the authentication process. Should you wish to add that in a part choosing to allow/disallow users, you need to write that yourself in the view function like `current_user.active`. I'll make an edit

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense. I'm working on fitting this into my code. I'll follow up here if I have any more issues.